# Toolbar with VLC ActiveX in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, api, activex, toolbar, vlc

I've used the **VideoLAN [VLC ActiveX](http://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX) Plugin 2** (available in the [VLC 0.9.4 installation](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html)) in my VB.NET App.

I've noticed that:

- The controller toolbar (seek bar, control buttons, volume) do NOT appear at all
- Even after playing a file
- And the **"Toolbar" property** cannot be set to TRUE, read-only?

So my questions are:

1. Is the **"Toolbar" property** a useless thing or is there a special way to get it to TRUE?
2. Will the **Toolbar appear** at all or would I have to implement it myself?
3. If I have to make a custom seek slider with control buttons, what are the **API calls** I can use to control media playback and seek-to-frame? VB.NET?
4. Is there **ANY other way** I can get the VLC player **with its Toolbar** in my App? [Libvlc?](http://wiki.videolan.org/Libvlc)

[image]

^ This is [the toolbar](https://wiki.videolan.org/images/Vlc-en.png) that I would like to have in my VB.NET App.

Answer (score 1):

the toolbar is not implemented on Windows VLC ActiveX control